Huygens' principle or finite speed of propagation?
I am reading the paper Large global solutions for energy supercritical nonlinear wave equations on $\mathbb{R}^{3+1}$ by Krieger and Schlag and am confused by one of their steps.
For context, $v(t,r)$ is radial and solves a septic nonlinear wave equation
$$-\partial_{tt}v + \Delta v = F(v),$$
on $(t,x)\in[T, T_1]\times \mathbb{R}^3$ where $F(v) = G(v) + g(r,t)$, where $G(0)=0$ and $g(r,t)$ is supported on $\{r=|x|<t+C\}$. We know that at time $T$, $v$ is supported in the ball $\{r=|x|\le T+C\}$ with $C>0$. The authors then claim, on page 34, that by Huygens' principle, it follows $v(r,t)$ is supported in the ball $\{r=|x|<t+C\}$ for each fixed $t\ge T$
However, I believe this simply follows from the finite propagation speed property of the wave equation. Is this correct, or is the Huygens' principle genuinely needed here?

I apologize, I have fixed the title.

Some clarification of terminology would help the question. In the literature on hyperbolic PDEs the term Huygens' principle refers to the property that a point disturbance creates a wave pulse that is supported only on the boundary of an expanding wave front (the forward Green function vanishes inside the future light cone). Hyperbolic equations by their nature do have finite speed of propagation, but do not always satisfy this stronger support property, in which case the Huygens' principle is said to fail. In this case, No this stronger property is clearly not needed.

As a remark, invoquing the finite propagation speed property for the wave equation is hand waving. How do one make this statement a rigorous mathematical concept ?
For a general hyperbolic PDE (or system of PDEs), you can make a definition, by looking at the velocity of planar waves. But then you have to transform this definition into a theorem and this requires pseudo-differential calculus.
For the wave equation, or more generally for so-called symmetric hyperbolic (systems of) PDEs, a much simpler proof occurs, which consists in integrating the energy equation
$$\partial_t\frac12(v_t^2+|\nabla v|^2)-{\rm div}(v_t\nabla v)=-v_tF(v)$$
over the characteristic cone $t\in(0,T)$, $|x|<t+c$.
Mind that you need of course $F(0)=0$.

To be clear then, Huygen's principle is not needed here and thus this type of result holds in even dimensions too.

Two points:
1.
In the wave equations community (in contrast to the community for more general hyperbolic systems) it is rather common to sloppily interchange "Huygen's Principle" with "finite speed of propagation". As a point of evidence: you will often find papers referring to the "sharp Huygen's principle" when the fact that the fundamental solution is a distribution supported on a cone is required. The adjective "sharp" is introduced precisely because the phrase "Huygen's principle" is often taken to refer to something more general.
2.
The (sharp) Huygen's principle is a statement about free propagation of linear waves in $\mathbb{R}^3$. It certainly does not hold for general nonlinear wave equations (the solution will scatter on itself and leave a tail).

Certainly Krieger and Schlag is simply referring to finite speed or propagation at that spot in their paper.

Q: Huygens' principle or finite speed of propagation?
It's the same thing, Huygens principle is a statement of causality, which means finite speed of wave front propagation.
Without Huygens principle you might imagine that the right-hand-side of the wave equation is a source term that allows a nonzero $v(x,t)$ to appear at $|x|>t+C$, without any relationship to the wavefronts at earlier times. The notion that a nonzero $v$ at some later time is causally related to a wavefront at an earlier time is the content of Huygens principle.
Note added in response to comment: the OP asks about $\mathbb{R}^3$, where all wavelets propagate with a single velocity $v\equiv 1$ and Huygens applies. In even dimensions all velocities $\leq v$ contribute. The support statement in the OP still holds, even though Huygens does not.

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huygens%E2%80%93Fresnel_principle :
In 1900, Jacques Hadamard observed that Huygens' principle was broken when the number of spatial dimensions is even.
Does this mean that for even number of spatial dimensions the speed of wave front propagation is infinite ?

It seems that the answer by Denis Serre works in any number of dimensions, whereas your answer implies that such a result only works in odd dimensions. What is the discrepancy?

I added more details on the source term $v$ in my question: it is the sum of $G(v)$, where $G(0)=0$ and a term $g(r,t)$ supported on ${|x|<t+C}$ for each fixed $t$. Does this form preclude the type of source term you mention above?

In even dimensions the propagation speed is no longer uniquely $v$, but all speeds $\leq v$ contribute. The maximum speed remains $v$, so the compact support statement in the OP  still holds.
